# Unit test not running in TFS build Release|x64 platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, tfsbuild, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have created unit test for my solution in which all projects are in 64 bit. The unit test is also 64 bit. When I try to run this in my local machine it is working fine. But when I use this in TFS build it says the unit test dll cannot be loaded..

Then I changed the Platform for unit test to AnyCPU and TFS build to Release|AnyCPU. This time when I run unit test via TFS build I am getting bad image exception for the assembly which I am unit testing.. I am not able to find a solution for this.

Comment: It's definitely the target platform setting. I've had this problem several times on different machine. Look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875108/system-badimageformatexception-caused-by-nunit-project)

Comment: Which TFS build are you using ? VNext or XAML build? There’s any error during TFS build log?

Answer (score 1):

Add a .runsettings file to your project and specify `<TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>` in it, and then configure to use the .runsettings file when you run the unit testing during the build.

See this article for details: [Run a unit test as a 64-bit process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782531.aspx).