# BadImageFormatException when running unit tests on build server

Tags: c#, jenkins, console, jenkins-pipeline, nunit

I have a suite of NUnit tests in a project with AnyCPU architecture. Some of these tests use types from an x86 (32-bit) assembly.

When I run the tests locally (via ReSharper), they all pass.

However, **when they're executed on Jenkins by using `nunit3-console MyProject.csproj` command, the tests that reference the 32-bit assembly fail with BadImageFormatException:**

```
System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly '...' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

How to make them pass?

Answer (score 0):

**`nunit3-console MyProject.csproj` runs the tests in 64-bit process by default**, which make it impossible to load 32-bit assemblies. This doesn't have anything to do with build server, so the same would happen on TeamCity etc.

## The solution is to force the runner to use 32-bit process by adding a proper flag: `nunit3-console MyProject.csproj --x86`.

Analogous problem with xUnit can be solved by running `dotnet xunit -x86`.

I think that for `dotnet test` the command `dotnet test --runtime win10-x86` (with proper system flag) would help.

#### Why the tests don't fail in ReSharper?

ReSharper test runner by default automatically chooses the "bittedness" of the process. Maybe it analyses assembly references in test files, I don't know. Anyway, in my case it was choosing 32-bit runner for my unit tests. When I forced it to use 64-bit (Unit Test Sessions —> Options —> Platform —> x64), a few tests failed with same message as on Jenkins.

Comment: FWIW NUnit also looks at the bitness of a test assembly by default. But it doesn't look at references, which is why the `--x86` option exists.